# KendoDataViz Line Graph : set marker visible for selected points only

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I have a line graph that has markers disabled by default

```
markers: {visible: false,size: 10}
```

On receiving the data, I want to be able to show the marker only for a few points

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The markers.visible can take either a boolean or a function.  Simply define a function for the visible property, and check the dataItem in that function call, and return either true or false.

```
series: [{
    type: "line",
    markers: {
      visible: isVisible
    },
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
}]
```

With the isVisible function defined like...

```
function isVisible(e) {
  return e.dataItem % 2 === 0;
}
```

Here is a sample displaying a simple line, but only the even values get markers.

http://jsbin.com/danoh/1/edit

Documentation... http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/dataviz/chart#configuration-series.markers.visible